# if app is login and its in background and click on app launcher icon from home screen it will display login screen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

for login:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref2 = getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String userid = sharedPref2.getString(SharedPref.USER_ID, user_id);
if (userid != null) {
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return;
 }
```

if App is opening from background then it will display HomeActivity properly ,
but when app is in background and open it from launcher icon then only it displays login screen .

Comment: have you saved user id after login?

Comment: Please edit your question with some clear idea

Comment: @VivekMishra yes userid is saved.

Comment: and in which method you have written above code?

Comment: @VivekMishra onCreate()..

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole code in a function and check if the user is logged in or not in your onCreate method of loginActivity.

```
@Override
onCreate(Bundle savedBundleState){
.....

if(isUserloggedIn()){
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    }

}


boolean isUserloggedIn(){ 
       String userid = sharedPref2.getString(SharedPref.USER_ID, user_id);
if (userid != null) {
    return true;
}
else{
return false;}
}
```

Comment: encourage helps by upvote and accept answer if you don't mind :)